# Как перенести сайт на битриксе на локальный сервер?

Tags: битрикс

Есть сайт на битриксе. Я его скачал, а как открыть на пк или в опен сервере? Что не пытаюсь открыть открывает только какой то код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: было бы не плохо хотя бы скрин увидеть

Comment: Добавил скрин кода.

Comment: Идите и читайте документацию по переносу сайта https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=8&CHAPTER_ID=120

Answer (score 0):

я так понимаю, все без установщика делалось, поэтому проблемы с коннектом к базе, вот ссылка на инструкцию: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=8&LESSON_ID=3171

нужно сделать бэкап сайта, затем с использованием `restore.php` (на сайте битрикса можно найти) развернуть у себя на локалке, при установке будут запрошены параметры БД и т.п.